# COPYING/CLONING ORACLE 10.2 XE FULL DATABASE TO ANOTHER MACHINE

Tags: oracle-xe

I HAVE ORACLE 10.2 XE INSTALLED AND WORKING ON WINDOWS XP SP3 (32BIT). I NEED TO TRANSFER FULL DATABASE TO ANOTHER MACHINE (SERVER 2008R2 -64 BIT). I TRIED EXP AND IMP BUT RESULTS WERE PARTIAL NOT FULL. DATA FOR SOME TABLES WAS IMPORTED BUT NOT FULL.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, Oracle XE is officially not supportet on 64-bit Windows, maybe this causes some errors.
Use datapump instead. Example for a full datapump export:

```
expdp sys/<password>@<yourDB> as sysdba full=Y directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=<filename>.dmp logfile=<logfile>.log
```